# Unable to redirect the output of each line read from the file and create a new file for each redirected output

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/home/vdabas2/file2"

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]];

 do

    pbreplay -O "$line" >> output

 done < "$file"
```

I am able to read a file line by line and the output of each line processed is being redirected to *output* by using the above shell script.

But I need a different file as a redirected output for each line processed and save it like *output1*, *output2* and so on. So, if there are 10 lines in that file which are being passed on as arguments then I need 10 output files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/home/vdabas2/file2"
i=1
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]];

 do

    pbreplay -O "$line" >> output.${i}
    ((i++))

 done < "$file"
```

Add increment for example.

Comment: This worked as expected! Thank you!
Now, what if, instead of giving the name as output.1, output.2... I give the name similar to as that of the line read.
For example, the line is /var/log/pb/iologs/xyz, then file created against this should have xyz as its name.

Comment: hm, you can try parse the line inside of the loop like this: ```outputname=$(echo "${line}" | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'); pbreplay -O "${line}" >> ${outputname}.${i}``` First command specify `/` as delimiter in `$line` and getting substring after last `/`, xyz in this case. But this solution works if only **all** `$line` are like directories names with slashes (`/`).  @VinayDabas

Comment: Smooth! Thank you so much!!